# Interesting tag section disappears when a user clicks on interesting tag

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

On the right hand side, a user can add some tags under the interesting tags section. And when the user click on one of the interesting tags, he can see only the questions which are tagged with the tag he clicked on. However, the interesting tag section has disappeared. So if the user wants to see any other interesting tag, he has to first click on Question tab (on which he can now see the interesting tag section) and then select any other interesting tag.

It would be really convenient, if the interesting tag section is available on all pages, so that the user does not have to go to the Questions tab to see the section.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed.

If there is a choice of multiple paths to make, it's generally good usability to keep that choice visible after selecting. Another option would be to provide a navigational way back at the same area, something like "Browsing [ruby], one of your [interesting tags]."

The tags probably weren't thought as navigation choice, but in effect they have that role as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the right hand side --> ?

At any rate, the "drill down" there is adding tags and making the tag combinations that are more and more specific. You can use the browser back button to get back to a previous tag combinations, or click the "tagged" tags at the top right to go to a top level tag.

Comment: Right ... yes ... edited the Q. My sense of direction has always been like that!

Comment: But that's when you click on the tagged section. How about having both tagged and interesting tags section so that when user clicks on tagged, he gets into more and more specific tags. But when he clicks on a tag in the interesting tags section, he sees questions for only the clicked tag.